# How to investigate critical server load reported by nagios3?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, troubleshooting

Nagios3 running on my Ubuntu Server occasionally sends me email reports similar to:

```
Notification Type: PROBLEM

Service: Current Load
Host: localhost
Address: 127.0.0.1
State: CRITICAL

Date/Time: Mon May 22 00:14:54 CEST 2017

Additional Info:

**CRITICAL - load average: 3.57, 21.36, 15.40**
```

(usually I get three emails in the row, Warning, Critical, Recovery, twice a day, regular hours)

How do I investigate which service causes this and how to trace when and what really happened?
(I suspect some of the websites run by Apache, which one? which URL actually?)

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your service an [event-handler](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/eventhandlers.html) which will execute a script each time your service comes to non-ok state.

Your script will be able to store for example the datas from a top command and a netstat or others tools (`cat /proc/stat`) which shows the usage of your system.

Answer (score 1):

If the load,memory or CPU's are causing the issue , you can configure [sysstat](https://crybit.com/sar-command/) utility to analyse the history of resource usage.

Answer (score 1):

I find it useful to configure Apache with a customized `LogFormat` that includes `%D`. That will log how many microseconds it took to process each request.

Since the duration being logged that way includes the time the server was waiting for the client, it is not a perfect metric to figure out which requests cause high load on the server. But it will still provide a useful signal about which URLs are likely to be causing high load on the server.

It is important to remember that load average is a very broad metric. It is a useful metric to know that you have a problem, but it is not so useful in figuring out what the problem is and how to fix it. In particular it covers both CPU load and I/O load, and the number itself does not tell you which of the two is the reason.

Looking at the output of tools like `top` and `iotop` during the period of high load can provide some hints.

Comment: I find this is _extremely_ useful when you also ship that data to ELK, then I can zoom down to pages that are too slow and put my site at risk with 592 and 503 errors)